# SQUID Proxy - does it have an interface for reviewing internet usage?

Tags: squid

Does SQUID (for Windows specifically) it have an interface for reviewing internet usage?

More specifically if I wanted a way to track, for my PC at work, it's internet usage on a per application/service basis (e.g. browser vs calendar synch service etc), would SQUID for Windows help me here?  (i.e. would it act as a transparent proxy for anything running on my PC, then keep a history of internet usage against which process requested the access)

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the same, but you could write scripts that parse the squid logs in `/var/log/squid` and compute metrics of interest.

Comment: no other targeted open source software comes to mind that would fit my requirements that you know of I don't suppose?

Comment: No, but try asking the same question on serverfault.com.